# Why does my Deep Learning Network converge to mean value of series when trying to fitting & predicting a time series?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, tensorflow, keras

There's a task requiring me to predict ***selling price*** of a product with provided **external** data containing historical **purchasing prices** and **selling prices of competitors**(positive correlated). Illustrations of **BRENT**(Competitor's), **PURCHASING PRICES** and **ACTUAL SELLING PRICE** are as follows:

[image: ORIGINAL TIME SERIES]

After filling *NA* values, I tried to make these time series stationary by $$ln(\frac{x_{t+1}}{x_t}+1)$$ and the stationary time series are illustrated as follows:

[image: STATIONARY TIME SERIES]

Then I made some moving windows whose sizes are all 6, indicating that each window contains data, including **selling prices**, of past 6 days. For each window, it had one **response**: selling price of the 7<sup>th</sup> day's. By moving the window, I could get a data set of 3-dimension: $(window\_num, 
window\_size=6, variable\_num=20)$, and the shape of **response set** is $(window\_num, 1)$.

With these preparations I started to fit the response set by corresponding data set. The model I used was ***Transformer*** implemented by **Keras** from an [instance](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/text_classification_with_transformer/) of its official site. The network's structure was as follows:

[image: NETWORK STRUCTURE]

After training for 500 epochs, *loss* and *MAE* were stable and MAE is illustrated as follows:

[image: MAE]

However, compared with the **actual response** and **origin price**, which are shown as follows:

[image: FITTING AND PREDICTING OF STATIONARY RESPONSE]

[image: FITTING AND PREDICTING OF ORIGIN PRICE]

The upper ones of these two plots are from fitting the **training** data, and the lower ones are predicting using **validation** data. It is shown that the outputs of my model converge to one straight line, and thus it could not seize any volatility of the *response*.

In another trial using NARX with MATLAB's **NEURAL TIME SERIES**, the series predicting result could be far more better (*AT LEAST IT SOMEWHAT CATCHES THE TREND*), so I considered the bad performance of my model was not caused by the data itself.

[image: NARX RESULT]

**I have been confused for a couple of weeks, could anyone help? Thanks so much for your patience and assistance.**

Answer (score 0):

Before training your NN you applied a transformation. This means that the NN learned to predict the stationary process, not the original prices. You need to reverse this transformation in order to compare with prices.

Comment: Hi Akylas Stratigakos, I suppose that this transformation of stationarity can ensure the statistical stability of time series for fitting and forecasting? Still I will give it a try, thanks!

Comment: After 10000+ epochs my model predicting origin price series (without stationarity) still turned out to be one straight line, should be the average value of the average prices, and the loss could barely reduce. So hopeless...